# How to customize bank details styles in Woocommerce order emails?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This section within Woocommerce order emails comes from the code in woocommerce/includes/gateways/class-wc-gateway-bacs.php

```
     /**
     * Get bank details and place into a list format.
     *
     * @param int $order_id Order ID.
     */
    private function bank_details( $order_id = '' ) {

        if ( empty( $this->account_details ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // Get order and store in $order.
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        // Get the order country and country $locale.
        $country = $order->get_billing_country();
        $locale  = $this->get_country_locale();

        // Get sortcode label in the $locale array and use appropriate one.
        $sortcode = isset( $locale[ $country ]['sortcode']['label'] ) ? $locale[ $country ]['sortcode']['label'] : __( 'Sort code', 'woocommerce' );

        $bacs_accounts = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bacs_accounts', $this->account_details, $order_id );

        if ( ! empty( $bacs_accounts ) ) {
            $account_html = '';
            $has_details  = false;

            foreach ( $bacs_accounts as $bacs_account ) {
                $bacs_account = (object) $bacs_account;

                if ( $bacs_account->account_name ) {
                    $account_html .= '<h3 class="wc-bacs-bank-details-account-name">' . wp_kses_post( wp_unslash( $bacs_account->account_name ) ) . ':</h3>' . PHP_EOL;
                }

                $account_html .= '<ul class="wc-bacs-bank-details order_details bacs_details">' . PHP_EOL;

                // BACS account fields shown on the thanks page and in emails.
                $account_fields = apply_filters(
                    'woocommerce_bacs_account_fields',
                    array(
                        'bank_name'      => array(
                            'label' => __( 'Bank', 'woocommerce' ),
                            'value' => $bacs_account->bank_name,
                        ),
                        'account_number' => array(
                            'label' => __( 'Account number', 'woocommerce' ),
                            'value' => $bacs_account->account_number,
                        ),
                        'sort_code'      => array(
                            'label' => $sortcode,
                            'value' => $bacs_account->sort_code,
                        ),
                        'iban'           => array(
                            'label' => __( 'IBAN', 'woocommerce' ),
                            'value' => $bacs_account->iban,
                        ),
                        'bic'            => array(
                            'label' => __( 'BIC', 'woocommerce' ),
                            'value' => $bacs_account->bic,
                        ),
                    ),
                    $order_id
                );

                foreach ( $account_fields as $field_key => $field ) {
                    if ( ! empty( $field['value'] ) ) {
                        $account_html .= '<li class="' . esc_attr( $field_key ) . '">' . wp_kses_post( $field['label'] ) . ': <strong>' . wp_kses_post( wptexturize( $field['value'] ) ) . '</strong></li>' . PHP_EOL;
                        $has_details   = true;
                    }
                }

                $account_html .= '</ul>';
            }

            if ( $has_details ) {
                echo '<section class="woocommerce-bacs-bank-details"><h2 class="wc-bacs-bank-details-heading">' . esc_html__( 'Our bank details', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h2>' . wp_kses_post( PHP_EOL . $account_html ) . '</section>';
            }
        }

    }
```

How can I override this section styles (headings + list) without it affecting all headings as recommended here: [How to stylize bank details in WooCommerce email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27310911/how-to-stylize-bank-details-in-woocommerce-email)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Look at the code that you copied into this question. It appears you want to use the filter `woocommerce_bacs_account_fields`

Comment: @HowardE, I'm not really sure how to use that filter in order to get what I need.